# Can Samba veto files,except specified directory?

Tags: debian, samba

OS:debian 6.0.3 kernel:2.6.32-5-adm64 samba 3.6.1 here is my smb.conf

```
[global]
   workgroup = Workgroup
   server string = Share Server
   hosts allow = 192.168.1.0/24
   wins support = yes
   dns proxy = no
   name resolve order = wins host lmhosts bcast
   interfaces = eth0
   bind interfaces only = yes
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   log level = 2
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 0
   security = user
   encrypt passwords = true
   smb passwd file = /etc/samba/smbpasswd
   unix password sync = no
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   unix extensions = no
   printcap name = /etc/samba/printcap
   load printers = no
   config file = /etc/samba/smb.conf.%U

[fileshare]
  comment = File Share
  path = /home/fileshare
  read only = no
  valid users = @files
  browseable = no
  writable = yes
  write list = @files
  create mask = 644
  directory mask = 755
  guest ok = no
  hide dot files = yes
  follow symlinks = yes
  wide links = yes
  veto files = /*.exe/*.com/*.dll/*.mp3/*.avi/*.mkv/*.msi/
```

Now user can't read/write exe file on /home/fileshare. I want /home/fileshare/soft dir not limit. I know, add a share tag can do it, e.g.

```
[soft]
  comment = software dir
  path = /home/fileshare/soft
  read only = no
  valid users = @files
  browseable = no
  writable = yes
  write list = @files
  create mask = 644
  directory mask = 755
  guest ok = no
  hide dot files = yes
  follow symlinks = yes
  wide links = yes
```

but I want login on //samba-server/fileshare/soft not //samba-server/soft, any ideas?

Comment: No.....................................................

Comment: only file extensions can be excluded https://askubuntu.com/a/1482940/828892